# How to compress .ttf font file size

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, fonts

I'm using noori nastaleeq font in my website but the .ttf file is around a 7mb file which is taking too much time to load the webpage, is there any way to compress the filesize? this font is not available on google fonts too.

P.S: The actual .ttf was around 12mb i'm using w3 super cache plugin so it compress the current file to 7mb and i wanted to compress more

Thanks

Comment: If you are legally allowed to create a subset font for this, do that first. Mine your content to find out which codepoints need to be supported, and which don't, and then create a subset font that only contains those codepoints and all gsub/gpos rules that involve those points (typically you automate that, and you use something like fontforge and its python programming API so you don't do this by hand)

Answer (score 6):

Try using font-squirrel to convert your font.  They have perfect instructions on their website.  After you convert your font, it also comes with a css file that includes your font already added to a `font-family`.  Easy to just plug into your html.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Yeah but they also generate font formats that don't even *exist* anymore so make sure to only get it to generate `woff` and `woff2` formats. Don't pick any of the other formats, they are not for modern browsers.

Comment: I tried and it told me that my ttf file was corrupt, whereas it's not

Comment: thank you. convertino is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Converting your font file `(.ttf extension)` to `.woff` or `.woff2`

the woff extension is more optimized comparing to .ttf

**Note:** consider that **IE11** didn't accept woff2 so use woff as its fallback.

Answer (score 0):

This ttf->woff2 converter website worked well for me: https://www.youcompress.com/ttf

Note that it apparently has an upload-file size-limit of 5mb. (not a problem in my case, but worth mentioning)